# How to convert variable to two dimensional array using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable which contains data like this

```
var values = "VItDTotal,123,234,234,2345,1234,123,435,10,TestCase,123,234,234,2345,1234,123,435,5"
```

and I want to convert this string of data to a two dimensional array like this

```
[VItDTotal,123,234,234,2345,1234,123,435,10] //1st row
[TestCase, 123,234,234,2345,1234,123,435,5]  //2nd row
```

How can I convert a JS variable to a two dimensional array?

I want to append these values to a datatable, how can I achieve this by using jQuery?

Comment: Can you not change the format the value is originally built as a comma-delimited string? It would be easier to change it there.

Comment: it's not a string,for the purpose of understanding ,I have used comma delimited values ,when I used alert(values),I have these values in my variable.

Comment: Ok, so if it's not a string, exactly what format do you have your data in? I presume it's an array? We need this information in order to help you most effectively.

Comment: Does my answer helped you? or still stuck?

Comment: I found the solution my self,thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help...

```
var values = "VItDTotal,123,234,234,2345,1234,123,435,10,TestCase,123,234,234,2345,1234,123,435,5"


var splittedArray = values.split(',')
var resultArray = new Array();
var resultKey = -1;
for(var i=0; i<splittedArray.length; i++) {
  if(isNaN(splittedArray[i])) {
    resultKey++;

    resultArray[resultKey] = new Array();
    resultArray[resultKey].push(splittedArray[i])
  } else {
    resultArray[resultKey].push(splittedArray[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the numeric strings converted to numbers as well in the `else`: `resultArray[resultKey].push(Number(splittedArray[i]))`

Comment: it was also said that his variable wasn't a string but an array so you don't need to do the string split

Answer (score 0):

I work this way:

```
//get the index where ",TestCase" is
var index = values.indexOf(",TestCase");

//create two arrays to the values
var part_one = [], part_two = [];

//slice the value from 0 to index and push part one
part_one.push(values.slice(0,index));

//slice the value from index+1 to the end and push part two
part_two.push(values.slice(index+1, values.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not my favourite, but, are you after something like this?

```
var values = ["VItDTotal",123,234,234,2345,1234,123,435,10,"TestCase",123,234,234,2345,1234,123,435,5];
var vals = [values.
    join(",").
    replace(/,([a-z]+)(?!.*[a-z]+)/gi, " devider $1").
    split(/\s+devider\s+/gi)];

console.log(vals);
```